# Make class from set of methods in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, methods, nsarray

I have a series of methods in a view controller that fill an array with data and also allow selection of various items within - works fine. Code is below (I took out the code within each method for clarity).

My question is: I reuse this code quite a bit and I am always copying and pasting this into new projects. I think it would be easier to access a class(?) that does all of the below instead of copying and pasting all of these methods into each vc. Then I could just reference the class file - cleaning up my code and reducing lines in the vc.

How can I convert these methods into something I can allocate(?) or call from within a view controller?

```
- (NSArray *)imageData {

        return __imageData;
}

       - (UIImage *)maskAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index maskType:(NSString*)maskName {

            return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];    
        }

        - (UIImage *)imageAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index phaseType:(NSString*)phaseName {

            return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];    
        }

        - (UIImage *)phaseaAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

            return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
        }

        - (NSString *)imageNameAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index phaseType:(NSString*)phaseName {

            return name;
        }

        - (NSString *)maskNameAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index maskType:(NSString*)maskName{

            return mask;
        }

        - (NSString *)phaseaNameAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

            return phasea;
        }

        - (CGSize)imageSizeAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

            return size;
        }

        - (NSUInteger)imageCount {

            return __count;
        }
```

Comment: Well I am at a loss on how to use this new category. I have set up my files but am unsure of how to cause them to be used.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of code should probably be in a category on UIImage.

See here: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Comment: Ahh! So the NSArray part would stay where it is but the UIImage methods would be added to the new category? Or can I also add the nsarray method (which loads a plist to get image names)?

Comment: A UIImage class method can return an NSArray, of course, so you can implement that in the UIImage category as well. You should be sure to use a class method instead of an instance method, though, because it doesn't really make sense to associate it with a single instance of a UIImage.

Comment: So I have created a category called UIImage+arrayindex. Added the above methods to both. I have imported the new category. In what way do I convert my existing methods that used to reference methods in the same vc to now see the category? The example string method from the link is not clear enough for me:   numberOfFrames = [self imageCount]-1;
 imageView.image = [self imageAtIndex: currentFrame phaseType:@"phase_b_base"];
 color.image = [self maskAtIndex: currentFrame maskType:@"phase_b_color"]; Also I appreciate your responses so far.

Comment: I also converted the NSArray to a + instead of a - (h&m) as I recall that is making it a class method, yes? Not sure how to use it of course but getting closer, maybe?